# Trying to grep part of a file name in shell script?

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I have a very simple grep problem but can't seem to solve it. I have several files like this:

```
sample.txt
sample7.doc.txt
another_sample.sample.lst.txt
three.txt
```

...And I just want to grab everything before the ".txt". I was trying to do this in shell script like this:

```
ame=`echo $1 | grep -Po "^[A-Za-z0-9]+"`
```

...But of course that returns only the portion up until the first 'dot'.  Can someone please help modify this regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for regexp:

```
$ basename sample.txt .txt
sample
```

or using any POSIX-compatible shell:

```
$ echo "$a"
sample.txt

$ y=${a%.txt}

$ echo "$y"
sample
```

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of 'basename'

Comment: That's a nice tool to have in your utility belt, together with `dirname`

Comment: @Kent That's Bourne Shell (sh), and has ever been.

Comment: Expansions need to be quoted to still work correctly for names containing whitespace or other IFS characters (or glob expressions).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
grep -Po '.*(?=\.txt$)'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. remove .txt

   name=`echo $1|sed 's/.txt$//'`
2. use basename

   name=`echo $fullname|basename .txt`

Comment: Tempted to -1 for not using double quotes around variables.

Answer (score 0):

## Here is the script for renaming file.

## Pass file name as argument

## !/bin/bash

mv $1 $(echo $1 | awk -F.txt '{print $1}')